# How to read a specific XML node?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have an XML file with data corresponding to multiple objects. I am trying to open the XML file, loop through to find a specific filename and read in all the values associated with that.

**Problem:**

It never has a match between an XMLElement's Name and the file name. So "I match the currently open file's name" never gets printed.

**What I want to happen:** So when a "dog.jpg" is opened by a user in the OpenFileDialog, the XML document gets loaded up and it should be able to find the XML element "Name" with the value dog.jpg and print "I match the currently open file's name".

*Also, I wanted to know how can I read other corresponding values once I get a match like the different distance values?*

Code in my Open method :

```
string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName; //file name of a JPEG file opened by a user
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\Users\Desktop\TangramsTool\patterndata.xml");
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Patterns/Pattern");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
         string text = node["Name"].InnerText; //or loop through its children as well
         if (text.Equals(fileName))
         {
              Console.WriteLine("I match the currently open file's name: " + text);
         }
         else
         {
              Console.WriteLine("This node's name is : " + text);
         }
    }
```

My XML file:

```
<Patterns>
     <Pattern> 
         <Name>dog.jpg</Name> 
         <PatternDistancesList>       
              <PatternDistance>278</PatternDistance>
              <PatternDistance>380</PatternDistance>
         </PatternDistancesList> 
     <Pattern/>
     <Pattern> 
          <Name>cat.jpg</Name> 
          <PatternDistancesList>       
              <PatternDistance>278</PatternDistance>
              <PatternDistance>380</PatternDistance>
          </PatternDistancesList> 
     <Pattern/>
</Patterns>
```

Comment: what do you get in the nodelist?

Comment: I get a list of the different <pattern> </pattern> nodes and then for each of them I read the "Name".

Comment: Try to find answer in linq.

Comment: XML is case sensitive , are you sure you have dog.jpg as the filename?

Comment: Ah silly mistake >.< my filename actually stored the entire path of the file (coming from OpenFileDialog) and I was comparing that to just dog.jpg. So they were indeed not the same. 
Thank you @Nikita

Comment: @Nikita would you happen to have any idea as to how I can read the different distance values for the dog.jpg pattern itself? Do I need to have another loop for that?

Comment: Yes, you can make it easier with LINQ.I will try to add an answer asap.

Comment: Can you have multiple records with name??

Comment: Ideally, only one record with a name should exist at any time, however my code doesn't check for that as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way using Linq. Answer includes your following query also.

> Also, I wanted to know how can I read other corresponding values once I get a match like the different distance values?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string uploadFilename = "dog.jpg";
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\admin\XMLFile1.xml");

            //// check if the xml file is having node mathcing upload filename name 
            List<XElement> xel = xdoc.Descendants("Name").Where(x => x.Value == uploadFilename).ToList();

            if (xel.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I match the currently open file's name: " + uploadFilename);

                //// Get list of element list's Ancestors
                //// will return
                ////<Name>dog.jpg</Name>
                ////<PatternDistancesList>
                ////  <PatternDistance>278</PatternDistance>
                ////  <PatternDistance>380</PatternDistance>
                ////</PatternDistancesList>

                //// looop through it
                foreach (XElement item in xel.Ancestors("Pattern").Elements().ToList())
                {

                }

                //// OR get another list
                List<XElement> foundItems = xel.Ancestors("Pattern").Elements().ToList();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is basic help using console application. Modify the code accordingly. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm trying to implement it now, I'm just wondering how will I only add the distance values to a new list (ignore the name and distancelist)?

Comment: I understood that you want the distance list values 278 and 380 mathcing name value.
`//// Result ill have list of string having value 278 and 380
                List<string> distanceValues = new List<string>();
                foreach (XElement item in xel.Ancestors("Pattern").Descendants("PatternDistance"))
                {
                    distanceValues.Add(item.Value);
                }`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :D I think I need to spend time reading about the entire tree structure in terms of Ancestors and Descendants to get a proper understanding of it.

Comment: Welcome buddy. Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

openFileDialog1.FileName returns the full path of the file 
use openFileDialog1.SafeFileName to get the filename only and you will have your desired result. The strings don't math because one of them gets the file name while the other gets the full path. use openFileDialog1.SafeFileName and i am sure you will get a match.

Comment: You're right! This was the exact problem I was having. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Get the filename from file dialog :

```
string fileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
```

Load the XmlDocument:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Desktop\TangramsTool\patterndata.xml");
```

Get the matching XElements:

```
var MatchingPatterns=xdoc.Elements("Pattern").Where(o=>o.Element(Name).Value.Trim()==filename).FirstOrDefault();

if(MatchingPatterns!=null)
{
 Console.WriteLine("I match the currently open file's name: " + fileName );
}
```

you can get the list of PatternDistance like this:

```
   List<XElement> patternDistances= MatchingPatterns.Element("PatternDistancesList").Elements("PatternDistance").ToList();
```

This might Help !

Comment: When I try to implement the last bit of code to store the values into a list, it gives an error saying: 
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'bool'

Comment: there is no bool value. the above solution works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your updated answer. With the exact same code, at the last line, now it gives this error 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Add ToList() to the last line.

Comment: Oh that's what I didn't make clear when using list. It works now :D Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Patterns>
     <Pattern> 
         <Name>dog.jpg</Name> 
         <PatternDistancesList>       
              <PatternDistance>278</PatternDistance>
              <PatternDistance>380</PatternDistance>
         </PatternDistancesList> 
     </Pattern>
     <Pattern> 
          <Name>cat.jpg</Name> 
          <PatternDistancesList>       
              <PatternDistance>278</PatternDistance>
              <PatternDistance>380</PatternDistance>
          </PatternDistancesList> 
     </Pattern>
</Patterns>

string fileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
```

Make sure that filename and node["Name"].InnerText are same

Comment: @Nikita- filename return full path and SafeFileName return filename with extension